# UINavigationItem appearance inconsistency

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

By default in our app we have the the following appearance for the UINavigationBarItems

```
NSDictionary *atts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor clearColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:atts forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:atts forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Basically we set the title transparent.

That affects to the potential integration with other components, like the UIImagePicker, but basically we roll back this appearance when we display the image picker.

```
NSDictionary *atts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor darkGrayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:atts forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:atts forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

But if in a UITextView we have a link or an e-mail, and with a 3D touch the system display a menu for Send a Message, or Add to Contacts, the app appear with the transparent buttons, making the usability poor.

**Workaround 1**

We detect in the viewWillDisappear if the view has been pop, or is just hidden because another component (image picker, add contact, sms ...)

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    BOOL isBeingRemoved = [self isMovingFromParentViewController] || self.isBeingDismissed;
    if (isBeingRemoved) {
        // Hidding the UINavigationBarItem title
        NSDictionary *atts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor clearColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
       [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:atts forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:atts forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    } else {
        // Make visible the UINavigationBarItem title
        NSDictionary *atts = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor darkGrayColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
       [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:atts forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:atts forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

But by doing this, the application appearance is updated, and the app title is no longer transparent.

**Workaround 2**

We tried to apply the transparent in viewWillAppear and to darkGray in viewWillDisappear, and works for the image picker, but not for the rest of the applications.

**Workaround 3**

We tried also to set the darkGrayColor without using the appearance in the viewWillDisappear, but didn't work.

```
self.navigationcontroller.navigationbar.titletextattributes
```

Any suggestions?